# Biblatex puts authors names after an article name if the number of authors is more than 3

Tags: biblatex, biber

If the number of authors is more than 3, biblatex puts authors names after an article like this

[image]

Although it should leave the names before the title of the article.

Biblatex settings:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-authoryear,language=auto,autolang=other,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specific feature of `biblatex-gost` styles, which implement the requirements of the Russian bibliography standard ГОСТ 7.0.5—2008, so I assume this behaviour is wanted.

The styles support the option `movenames=false,` to stop moving names to after the title. Unfortunately, I don't read Russian very well, but the [documentation of the style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-gost/doc/biblatex-gost.pdf) has some more details about the option that may interest you.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999, movenames=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,herrmann}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Herrmann W. A., Öfele K., Schneider S. K., Herdtweck E., Hoffmann S. D. A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for C–C coupling reactions // Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. — 2006. — Vol. 45, no. 23. — P. 3859–3862.]

Comment: It helped, thx.